# Need specific number format in Oracle S9(15)V9(2)

Tags: oracle, formatting, numbers

I have a requirement to produce amount fields in zoned decimal format with this specific syntax below.

I don’t know if I need to create a function to handle this or if I can tweak the Oracle number format model. I’m thinking it might require some conditional formatting within a function due to the different requirement for number of digits between positive and negative. I will be performing this formatting on a couple of dozen data elements in the procedure so that might be another reason to use a function. Thoughts?

Requirement:
Amount should be represented by 17 characters (positive number) or 16 characters plus a “}” appended to the end (negative number).

Ex. `0.00` should show as `00000000000000000`.
Ex. `-935,560.00` should show as `00000000093556000}`

Using Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, the *input* is already formatted and its datatype is `VARCHAR2`. If that's so, then this might do the job:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select        '0.00' from dual union all
  3     select       '25.34' from dual union all
  4     select '-935,560.00' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7    lpad(translate(col, 'x,.-', 'x'),
  8         case when substr(col, 1, 1) = '-' then 16
  9              else 17
 10         end, '0') ||
 11    case when substr(col, 1, 1) = '-' then '}'
 12         else null
 13    end result
 14  from test;

COL         RESULT
----------- --------------------
0.00        00000000000000000
25.34       00000000000002534
-935,560.00 0000000093556000}

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 5 - sample data
- line #7 - `translate` removes minus sign, commas and dots
- lines #7 - 10 - `lpad` pads the *number* (without characters from the previous step) with zeros up to the length of 16 (for negative values) or 17 (for positive values) characters
- lines #11 - 13 - if it is a negative value, concatenate `}` to the end of the result string

Comment: Littlefoot, thank you for the suggestion.  I like this approach and will compare to the suggestion my colleage provided here
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=converting-numbers

I do have a slightly different requirement for my rate syntax, for numbers such as interest rates.  Do you have any suggestions here?

Rate = 2.25% should show as    002250000
Rate = 3.85687 should show as 038568700

Comment: Rates should be represented in S9(3)v9(6) format 
Rate = 2.25% should show as    002250000
Rate = 3.85687 should show as 038568700